# Why does OpenCL apply code placed in the else part of my condition when the condition result is true

Tags: macos, opencl

I just started to develop with openCL, and I'm really confused by the result I get when I launch my kernel.

```
kernel void clTest1(read_only image2d_t input, write_only image2d_t output)
{
    size_t  x           = get_global_id(0);
    size_t  y           = get_global_id(1);
    bool    yIsEven     = ((y % 2) == 0);
    int     modifiedY   = 0;

    if (yIsEven) {
    modifiedY = y;
    } else {
    modifiedY = (y - 1);
    }

    printf("Original Y:%i isEven:%i Modified Y: %i", y, yIsEven, modifiedY);

    write_imageui(output, (int2)(x,y), read_imageui(input, sampler, (int2)(x,modifiedY)));
}
```

If I look at the console log,

I get the following result:
Original Y:0 isEven:1 Modified Y: 0
Original Y:1 isEven:0 Modified Y: 0
Original Y:2 isEven:1 Modified Y: 1
Original Y:3 isEven:0 Modified Y: 2
Original Y:4 isEven:1 Modified Y: 3
Original Y:5 isEven:0 Modified Y: 4
Original Y:6 isEven:1 Modified Y: 5
Original Y:7 isEven:0 Modified Y: 6
Original Y:8 isEven:1 Modified Y: 7
Original Y:9 isEven:0 Modified Y: 8

Instead of
Original Y:0 isEven:1 Modified Y: 0
Original Y:1 isEven:0 Modified Y: 0
Original Y:2 isEven:1 Modified Y: 2
Original Y:3 isEven:0 Modified Y: 2
Original Y:4 isEven:1 Modified Y: 4
Original Y:5 isEven:0 Modified Y: 4
Original Y:6 isEven:1 Modified Y: 6
Original Y:7 isEven:0 Modified Y: 6
Original Y:8 isEven:1 Modified Y: 8
Original Y:9 isEven:0 Modified Y: 8

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Which OpenCL device is this running on? Does this happen on all the OpenCL devices in your system? Since this is Apple's OpenCL implementation, I wouldn't be at all surprised if this was their bug.

Comment: Result posted are using OpenCL device: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M.

Comment: Results are correct when using OpenCL device: Intel Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3720QM CPU @ 2.60GHz

Comment: My only logical explanation is that the code you are actually running is different to the code you think you are running. Since the code is perfectly ok as it is. Try to put on purpose an error and see the results.

Comment: if (yIsEven == true) {
  modifiedY = y;
 } else {
  modifiedY = y + 1;
 }
There is no logic...  when I put this code, the result is good (modified Y is incremented)

Comment: You could try upgrading the OpenCL driver, maybe is an already fixed bug

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, and works for me. Given that it works for you on the CPU but not on the GPU, this would appear to be a bug in Apple's OpenCL implementation, which is not at all uncommon.

I recommend you raise a bug using the [Apple Bug Tracking System](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing this:

```
 printf("Original Y:%i isEven:%i Modified Y: %i", (int)y, (int)yIsEven, (int)modifiedY);
```

I don't really trust the vararg works ok for the GPU enviroment and bool types casting.

PD: In either way, is an Apple OCL problem, the results should be fine.

Comment: I tried using your code, but the result are the same.

Answer (score 0):

When I built your code with slight edits (see below) using `clang` , I got the LLVM IR below:

```
$ cat go.ll 
; ModuleID = 'go.cl'
target datalayout = "e-i64:64-v16:16-v32:32-n16:32:64"
target triple = "nvptx64-nvidia-nvcl"

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind
define void @clTest1(i32* nocapture readnone %input, i32* nocapture %output) #0 {
  %1 = tail call i64 @get_global_id(i32 0) #2
  %2 = tail call i64 @get_global_id(i32 1) #2
  %3 = and i64 %2, 1
  %4 = icmp eq i64 %3, 0
  %5 = add nsw i64 %2, 4294967295
  %modifiedY.0.in = select i1 %4, i64 %2, i64 %5
  %modifiedY.0 = trunc i64 %modifiedY.0.in to i32
  %6 = getelementptr inbounds i32* %output, i64 %1
  store i32 %modifiedY.0, i32* %6, align 4, !tbaa !3
  ret void
}
```

So you can see that `%modifiedY` gets the result of `select(yIsEven, y, modifiedY)`.  Note that the order of args is different between the [OpenCL `select`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/select.html) and [LLVM IR `select`](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#select-instruction).

Long story short: your code as written should work as described.  If it doesn't, it's a bug in your OCL provider or environment somehow.

"slight edits":

```
$ diff -Naur go_orig.cl go.cl 
--- go_orig.cl  2014-04-29 08:14:24.453488798 -0500
+++ go.cl   2014-04-29 08:15:01.657489768 -0500
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@

-kernel void clTest1(read_only image2d_t input, write_only image2d_t output)
+kernel void clTest1(read_only int *input, write_only int *output)
 {
     long  x           = get_global_id(0);
     long  y           = get_global_id(1);
@@ -12,7 +12,5 @@
         modifiedY = (y - 1);
     }

-    printf("Original Y:%i isEven:%i Modified Y: %i", y, yIsEven, modifiedY);
-
-    write_imageui(output, (int2)(x,y), read_imageui(input, sampler, (int2)(x,modifiedY)));
+    output[x] = modifiedY;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing OpenCL optimisation in the project's build settings.

OPENCL_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0